# Not able to configure Caddy server to use TLS with my domain name

Tags: webserver, caddy, caddyfile

I already have pointed domain's `A/AAAA` records point to my server's `IP` address and I do see `Caddy` home page when I put my server's `IP` address in the browser but not with domain name.

Not sure if my `Caddyfile` changes are even getting reloaded.

**Hit in browser:**

```
http://10.20.30.40 -- I see Caddy home page when I hit my machine's ip address
http://www.mytekworld.com -- The browser just keeps spinning when I hit the domain name
https://www.mytekworld.com -- The browser just keeps spinning when I hit the domain name
```

**sudo nano /etc/caddy/Caddyfile**

```
# The Caddyfile is an easy way to configure your Caddy web server.
#
# Unless the file starts with a global options block, the first
# uncommented line is always the address of your site.
#
# To use your own domain name (with automatic HTTPS), first make
# sure your domain's A/AAAA DNS records are properly pointed to
# this machine's public IP, then replace the line below with your
# domain name.
www.mytekworld.com

# Set this path to your site's directory.
root * /usr/share/caddy

# Enable the static file server.
file_server

# Another common task is to set up a reverse proxy:
# reverse_proxy localhost:8080

# Or serve a PHP site through php-fpm:
# php_fastcgi localhost:9000

# Refer to the Caddy docs for more information:
# https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile
```

**--Reload caddy**

```
caddy reload
sudo systemctl reload caddy --caddy.service is not active, cannot reload.
```

**Firewall status:**

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22000                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 80,443/tcp                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 22786 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 5] 80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 6] 8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a DNS issue.

Make sure your A record looks something like this

```
A 10.20.30.40
```

If your A record is formatted properly please update your question with the DNS record and your DNS provider (Cloudflare, Netlify, Godaddy, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. That IP was just for information. I have a different IP Address then the one mentioned above and is correctly configured in Godaddy. Moreover I got the issue resolved by starting Caddy after going into the directory /etc/caddy/ and then starting caddy from there.